# How to convert unix timestamp and aggregate min and max date in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, timestamp

I have table in Oracle SQL like below:

```
ID   | date          | place
-----------------------------
123  | 1610295784376 | OBJ_1
444  | 1748596758291 | OBJ_1
567  | 8391749204754 | OBJ_2
888  | 1747264526789 | OBJ_3
```

- ID - ID of client
- date - date in Unix timestamp in UTC
- place - place of contact with client

And I need to aggregate above date to achieve results as below, so I need to:

1. convert unix timestamp in UTC from column "date" to normal date as below
2. calculate min and max date for each values from column "place"

   | min_date | max_date | distinct_place |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 2022-01-05 | 2022-02-15 | OBJ_1 |
   | 2022-02-10 | 2022-03-20 | OBJ_2 |
   | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-21 | OBJ_3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
         + MIN(date_column) * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND(3)
         AS min_date,
       TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
         + MAX(date_column) * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND(3)
         AS max_date,
       place
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY place;
```

*Note: the `(3)` after `SECOND` is optional and will just explicitly  specify the precision of the fractional seconds.*

or:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( MIN(date_column) / 1000, 'SECOND')
         AS min_date,
       TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( MAX(date_column) / 1000, 'SECOND')
         AS max_date,
       place
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY place;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, date_column, place) AS
SELECT 123, 1610295784376, 'OBJ_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 444, 1748596758291, 'OBJ_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 567, 1391749204754, 'OBJ_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Fixed leading digit
SELECT 888, 1747264526789, 'OBJ_3' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE | PLACE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-01-10 16:23:04.376000000 UTC | 2025-05-30 09:19:18.291000000 UTC | OBJ_1 |
> | 2014-02-07 05:00:04.754000000 UTC | 2014-02-07 05:00:04.754000000 UTC | OBJ_2 |
> | 2025-05-14 23:15:26.789000000 UTC | 2025-05-14 23:15:26.789000000 UTC | OBJ_3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ade2e6366d2d434d4bdfb0b50e43ebd)*

Comment: @Serg Thanks, I was just working through that and its now fixed.

Comment: MT0 I have erro using your code: PaseException can not recognize input near '(' '3' ')' ...

Comment: @dingaro The `(3)` after the `SECOND` specifies the precision of the fractional seconds in the interval but it is optional so you can remove it; however, that code works for me in the linked db<>fiddle in Oracle 11, 18 and 21 so it should not cause any errors if you are running it natively. If you are running it through 3rd party software first then it may not recognize the valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: After using your new answer I have error: "Invalid function NUMTODSINTERVAL" what can I do ?

Comment: @dingaro Are you sure you are using an Oracle database?

Comment: hmm it could be also Hive SQL or Oracle SQL but it is on SQL Developer

Comment: @dingaro Oracle SQL Developer is not a database; it is a client application that can connect to multiple different RDBMS and not only an Oracle database. The syntax I have given you is valid for an Oracle database. If it is not working for you then that suggests that you are not using an Oracle database; you need to work out what you are using and then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for the new RDBMS (do not edit this question to change the tags for a new database).